# Decline mail not sent to organizer for Google Calendar Event created using API

Tags: google-calendar-api

Context:

1. User1 create an event on Google Calendar and invites User2 on it.
2. User2 receives a mail for the event from where he can accept/decline/Maybe this invitation.
3. User2 declines the event.
4. So here, User2 receives a mail saying User1 declined that particular event.

Now I do the same process using the Calendar API. Everything works as expected except for the fact that when User2 declines the event, User1 doesn't receive any mail for the same.

Am I missing anything here? Is there any parameter that I am missing to set in the event while creating the event.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. I think it'd help us to see if something's amiss if you post the related code snippets. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `sendNotification` parameter while creating the event. This parameter decides whether to send notifications about the event update - including attendee's responses-. It is false by default.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert